# Two WSO2 API Manager for Internal and External use

Tags: soap, soa, wso2-api-manager

1. Is it a common practice to have one API Manager for external user (and **internal** developers/publishers) and another one for internal users/developers/publishers?
2. If I have SOAP services in the backend, does that mean I should expose them as SOAP APIs in my internal API Manager? Do the consumers still need to generate the stubs?

Comment: Could you clarify point 2 a little. You have SOAP services in the back end and you want to expose them to the internal API manager according to the sentence but will the internal API manager not run on the back end?

Comment: The internal API manager is running in the backend (in the intranet). What I really want is to use the API manager's lifecycle management features. But since all the backend services are SOAP based, I am just wondering all the APIs in the internal manager should also  be SOAP based.

Comment: this is a bit of a depends answer. So I am just trying to put the rather long answer into a more short consice form

Answer (score 0):

yes you can have external setup for external users and internal setup for internal users.
when come to developers you can setup a dev environment for them.
once api is developed by developers. It can be given for QA.For that you can setup a test environment. once tested you can delpoly your api in production environment.production environment will have external and internal setup.

api manager supports rest to soap conversion . So that is not necessary that you want to create your api to only support soap